# Writing equation of curve using sin(s) in Lax's proof

Tags: calculus, inequality

I am going through Peter Lax's proof of the isoperimetric inequality.
It seems elegant, however, it doesn't seem to be written in a manner that undergraduate students can understand quickly. There are a few things I do not understand. The paper is titled [A shortest path to the shortest path](http://ocw.nctu.edu.tw/course/fourier/supplement/short%20path.pdf).

Here, he claims that the curve $y=f(x)$ which is parametrized by $x(s),y(s)$ where $s$ is the arc length ($0\leq s\leq\pi$) can be re-written since it was chosen such that $y(0)=y(\pi)=0$.

In particular, $y(s)=u(s)\sin s$ where $u(s)$ is bounded and differentiable

I don't understand how he got this. How did he obtain equation (4)?
It feels right, I would like to understand the reason why he can do that though.

The proof is found in the provided link.

Answer (score 1):

For $0<s<\pi$, we can write $y(s)=u(s)\sin s$ because $\sin s\ne0$ in this region.
(Just divide by $\sin s$ to have an explicit definition of $u(s)$.)

The only possible difficulty is at the ends of the interval. It is not clear if $u$ needs to have a limit at the end points for the proof to work, though.

As is stated in the paper, at least $u$ is bounded. This is because $s$ is arclength and $y(0)=0$, so $|y(s)|\le s$, which makes $y(s)/\sin s$ bounded near $s=0$. The same happens at the other end, since $y(\pi)=0$ as well (i.e., $|y(s)|\le \pi-s$).